# Solve an equation system with variables that are raised to decimal power

Tags: systems-of-equations, decimal-expansion

I've three equations and want to calculate the values of the three variables $x$, $y$ and $z$.
The problem is, that $x$ and $y$ are raised to decimal power and I don't know how to deal with them.

The equations are:

$I: 8x^{-0.6}y^{0.6}-8z=0$

$II: 12x^{0.4}y^{-0.4}-3z=0$

$III: -8x-3y+10000=0$

I've multiplied the first equation with $3$, the second one with $-8$ and  formed the third equation to get $x$ alone on one side. When I put it all together I get: $\frac{24y^{0.6}}{(\frac{10000-3y}{8})^{0.6}}-\frac{96(\frac{10000-3y}{8})^{0.4}}{y^{0.4}}=0$

When I use a tool to calculate it, I get $y=2000$ as a result, but I don't know how to get to this by hand. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the decimal exponent of $x$ and $y$?
Is there maybe an easier way to solve this equation system?

Comment: Try converting them to fractions at the very beginning.

Comment: It may be useful to observe that the usual English term for "potency" in this context is "exponent(s)".  It's not a perfect substitute—for instance, I might rather say that "$x$ and $y$ are raised to decimal (or fractional) powers" rather than "$x$ and $y$ have decimal numbers in their exponents"—but it's probably less prone to confusion than "potency".

Comment: Thanks for this great idea.

Comment: @JeanMarie I meant the comment of Franklin P. Dyer, which helped me to solve my problem. (I haven't seen the other comment of Brian Tung before posting.)

Comment: Misinterpretation on my side, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminating $z$ from the first two equations, you should get
$$\frac{24 y^{0.6}}{x^{0.6}} = \frac{96 x^{0.4}}{y^{0.4}} $$
and clearing out the denominators and dividing by $24$ should give you 
$$ y = 4 x $$
Now plug that in to the third equation, and solve.